# Angular 2 background tasks

Tags: angular

I am trying to figure out if its possible to have background running process while the angular2 application is running.

Example:

1. on application login have task that constantly checks the expiration
   of token and if it expires, redirect to login
2. have a task running in background to get latest updates from web api (i.e. inbox)

With old school MVC models i used it was a lot simpler cron job that pushed to view layer, not sure what is possible with angular2.

Answer (score 0):

For 1, you can use [Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers). There is one little thing to remember about Web Worker is that, inside one, you **can't** modify the DOM, you have to pass messages to the main thread to have it do so

For 2, you can use [Web Socket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) or Web Worker to do data streaming